# because ottomate_a depends on both aws_common ^0.4.1 and flutter_test from sdk, version solving failed

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

Because every version of `flutter_test` from sdk depends on `async 2.9.0` and `aws_common >=0.4.1` depends on `async ^2.10.0`, `flutter_test` from sdk is incompatible with `aws_common >=0.4.1`.

So, because ottomate_a depends on both `aws_common ^0.4.1` and `flutter_test` from `sdk`, version solving failed.

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.18.4 <3.0.0'


dependencies:
  get: ^4.6.5
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


 
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  intl_phone_field: ^3.1.0
  intl_phone_number_input: ^0.7.2
  country_picker: ^2.0.19
  otp_text_field: ^1.1.3
  amplify_flutter: ^1.0.0
  async: ^2.9.0
  aws_common: ^0.4.1


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

 
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
  introduction_screen: ^3.1.1
```